# Modelica: check equality of replaceable package or model

Tags: user-interface, types, parameters, modelica, isinstance

In my Modelica system model, I have a replaceable package (medium, fluid properties) and a replaceable model (pressure loss model). Can I somehow check whether a certain model or package is selected? The following approach does not work, but maybe explains what I want to achieve:

```
replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.WaterIF97_ph;
Boolean isWater = (Medium == Modelica.Media.Water.WaterIF97_ph);
```

I was thinking of something similar like in python, were you can use `type(variable)` or `isinstance(object, class)`. This approach seems to be doable in many languages, but is it possible in Modelica?

One workaround I thought of was to add some (or use an existing) constant inside the replaceable model/package and use that in the comparison, e.g. `constant String mediumName` or `constant Integer correlationID`, but I would see that as a workaround.

The workaround seems to work when using Integers, but not when using Strings. Any comment?

With comparison of constant Integer, I can calculate the correct value for the Boolean, but I hit another problem (in Dymola at least): When I use the Boolean in the annotation Dialog enable, it does not work. Is there a rule when the value of the Boolean gets evaluated?

Comment: See getInstanceName() operator.

Comment: @Adrian Pop: getInstanceName() does not return the class path.

Comment: I guess it depends on the tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The medium packages already have a property `mediumName` that you can compare, for instance using the code:

```
Boolean isWater = Modelica.Utilities.Strings.isEqual("WaterIF97", Medium.mediumName);
```

Best regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Thanks, that is what I tried and why I mentioned mediumName. I also edited my question to make it more clear I used that existing constant. Some problems: Not all media have mediumName defined; mediumName may be ambiguous (DryAir and Moist Air might both use mediumName="Air"; and even if the Boolean value is calculated correctly, I failed to successfully use it in the parameter dialog enable=Boolean.

Comment: The enable-attribute works best with parameter-expressions. 
I noticed that "isWater" isn't declared as parameter
More importantly generally using expressions in the enable attribute works better than indirectly referring to a parameter with that expression, so enable=Modelica... - but Medium.mediumName might be problematic anyway.